# PHP save array in cookie

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, serialization

I want to shuffle an array then serialized it and save it as a cookie.

```
$random_ads = array(
    '<li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>'
);
shuffle($random_ads);
$ra_serialized = serialize($random_ads);
setcookie('random_ads', $ra_serialized, time()+3600*24, '/');
```

Then I tried to use unserialized($_COOKIE['random_ads']) and print the array, but did not work. It print nothing. Please give me some ideas. The main thing I want is to save the array in cookie and get it back when I want. Thanks.

Comment: It works fine for me! Did you `unserialize()` it again?! So something like this: `print_r(unserialize($_COOKIE["random_ads"]));` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: I can't reproduce. I'm running your code and I get the expected result. PHP-5.5.19.

Comment: What is your php version? Also please show us the full script you use

Comment: I have edited my question after debugging a bit more ..

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
$random_ads = array(
    '<li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>'
);
shuffle($random_ads);
$ra_serialized = serialize($random_ads);
setcookie('random_ads', $ra_serialized, time()+3600*24, '/');
$getarray = unserialize($_COOKIE['random_ads']);
foreach($getarray as $getarray1)
{
    echo $getarray1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode($random_ads) or just join('|', $random_ads) and then parse it in on the client-side.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with json!

Answer (score 0):

After browsing for some hours, I found this solution and it works!

```
//to safely serialize
$safe_string_to_store = base64_encode(serialize($multidimensional_array));

//to unserialize...
$array_restored_from_db = unserialize(base64_decode($encoded_serialized_string));
```

Read more about this solution **[HERE](http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues)**